# Q: ImageMagick batch operations

Tags: imagemagick

I am trying to insert `image` into another `image` with ImageMagick. I want to do it in `batch` mode.

```
/images_to_insert/1.jpg 2.jpg 3.jpg 4.jpg...
/background_images/1.jpg 2.jpg 3.jpg
```

I am using this command:

```
composite images_to_insert/1.jpg -gravity center background_images/1.jpg results/result-%d.jpg
```

It works fine for one image, how to do it in batch mode for whole images? I tried this command without a luck:

```
composite images_to_insert/*.jpg -gravity center background_images/*.jpg results/result-%d.jpg
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for i in images_to_insert/*
do
    composite $i -gravity center background_images/$(basename $i) results/result-$(basename $i)
done
```

Comment: You should always double quote shell variables whenever you use them in case filenames have spaces in them... don't use `$i`, instead use `"$i"`.